# Auto play a sound when receive a new row data in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, woocommerce

I am developing a Vue app to fetch orders from Woocommerce REST API. So i am having a HTML Table to fill the JSON Data. So when each order receive to Woocommerce, I will get it in my dashboard using "setInterval" for 60 seconds through refreshing data. Also the flags are set to notify new order in the HTML table using colors.
Apart from this I need to play a sound in the Vue app whenever the Woocommerce receives an order. How can I archive this as a stable function?

My JS code

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      orders: []
    },
    mounted: function() {
  // Call the API the first time
  this.refreshData()
  // Then call the API every minute
  this.setIntervalId = setInterval(this.refreshData, 60000)
},
beforeDestroy: function() {
  // Stop refreshing data after the component is destroyed!
  clearInterval(this.setIntervalId)
},
methods: {  
  refreshData () {
    axios.get('https://mysite/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?per_page=20&consumer_key=key1&consumer_secret=key2')
    .then(response => {
      
      const previouslyFlaggedIds = this.orders.filter(x => x.is_printed).map(x => x.id);
      this.orders = response.data.map(x => ({...x, is_printed: previouslyFlaggedIds.find(y => y === x.id) != null}));
      console.log(response);
     })
     .catch(error => {
       console.log(eror);
    });
  },
  printBill(order) {  
    //change flag
    order.is_printed = true;    
  }
}    
})
```

HTML

```
<div class ="container mt-5" id="app">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
               
                <th scope="col">Order id</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Order Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Phone</th>
                <th scope="col">Address</th>
                <th scope="col">Items</th>
                <th scope="col">Total</th>
                <th scope="col">Print</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr
              v-for="(order, index) in orders" 
              :key="order.id"
              :class="{highlight: !order.is_printed}"
              > 
                    <td>{{ order.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ order.billing.first_name + " " +order.billing.last_name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ order.date_created }}</td>
                    <td>{{ order.billing.phone}}</td>
                    <td>{{ order.billing.address_1 + ", " + order.billing.address_2 + ", " + order.billing.city + order.billing.postcode }}</td>
                    <td>{{ order.line_items[0].name}} </td>
                    <td>{{ order.total}}</td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-primary" @click="printBill(order)">Print</button>
                      
                  </tr>
            </tbody>            
          </table>
```

Comment: I know this isn't what you asked for, but having done case studies on this, please don't. Instead, update the title of the page.

Comment: Acyually I need to notify my client when new orders arrives. Because its an app for restaurant, so often we get orders....

Comment: you can use push notification for alart

Comment: Hi, how can I implement that, by using any service like One signal???

Answer (score 0):

You can use [audio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio) tag for this.

```html
<audio
  ref="audio"
  src="/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3">
</audio>
```

Then after you receive the new orders just play the audio

```js
this.$refs.audio.play()
```

JSFiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/ztyvkLgn/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it did not work it to me, as i just copied your code in to my file....